# Test for Json transformers in Play framework 2.x

Tags: json, unit-testing, testing, playframework-2.0, transform

I wrote three simple json transformers with validations

```
val validateDefaultReminderMethod = Reads.pattern("email|sms|popup".r, "error.reminder.method (pattern: email|sms|popup)")

val validateDefaultReminderMinutes = Reads.min(0) keepAnd Reads.max(40320)

val validateDefaultReminder = (
    (__ \ "method").json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString] keepAnd validateDefaultReminderMethod) and
      (__ \ "minutes").json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsNumber] keepAnd validateDefaultReminderMinutes)
    ).reduce
```

for unit testing first two transformers i can use simple test like

```
"Default Reminder Method validator" must {
    "is successful for email value" in {
      JsString("email").validate(validateDefaultReminderMethod) must be (JsSuccess("email"))
    }
    ...
}
```

but I can not understand, how I must test third transformer. It consists of the first two, but how can I check this? So I must wrote same tests for third transformer?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
case class MyClass(method: String, minutes:Int)

"validateDefaultReminder" must {
    "is successful for email value and minutes" in {
        val json = Json.parse("""{ "email: "a@gmail.com", "minutes": 45}""")              
        json.validate[MyClass](validateDefaultReminder) must be JsSuccess
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If `validateDefaultReminder` will be changed (for example method pattern will be removed) test will be successful, but must fail. So i must wite same test for complex transformer too.

Comment: It will pass because you removed a validation. this is how the code will actually run, so I am not sure what is the problem here? you want the test to fail if the code was changed? and not when the logic is broken? if so you need to test the transformer definitions and not the transformer logic.

Comment: I cant understand how test, because if I have tested class, and I have value of this class in another class, I sure how second class wil work. But with transformers I don't know from what he gathered.